# Cannot use [UIApplication sharedApplication]. How can I register for notifications outside UIApplicationDelegate?

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications, uiapplicationdelegate, watchkit, uiapplication

I'm writing an application with a WatchKit extension.

I used to be able to register for notifications outside UIApplicationDelegate using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForNotificationTypes:]`.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication]` is now unavailable in projects containing a WatchKit extension.

How would I go about registering for notifications outside UIApplicationDelegate now?

For clarity: I am trying to register for notifications in my containing app, not the watchkit extension.

Answer (score 0):

A WatchKit extension is not allowed to send notifications.

Please use the containing app to do this feature and then, in the WatchKit extension you'll be able to show and customize the appearance of the notification.

Comment: Absolutely, but I need to register for notifications in the iOS app and if I'm compiling the application with an embedded WatchKit extension, [UIApplication sharedApplication] is not available.

Comment: This question isn't related to WatchKit then. In any case, that method is deprecated in iOS 8. Please use: registerUserNotificationSettings

Answer (score 0):

Like for any iOS extension*, the code (source file) which is part of WatchKit extension target cannot access a sharedApplication object, and so you cannot use any of the methods on that object. For code (source file) which is part of your App's main target (and not of WatchKit extension target), you can still use the below call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForNotificationTypes:]
```

So probably you are using this call from some source file which is added in your WatchKit Extension target.

*[App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

Comment: This is no longer correct as of WatchKit 2. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270738/what-is-the-equivalent-of-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-in-watchkit

Answer (score 0):

As of WatchKit 2, circumstances have substantially changed. You can now [access a shared delegate object in the WatchKit App Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270738/what-is-the-equivalent-of-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-in-watchkit), and by accessing the [WKExtensionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015523) you have access to six notification-related methods:
`didReceiveRemoteNotification(_:)`
`didReceiveLocalNotification(_:)`
`handleActionWithIdentifier(_:forRemoteNotification:)`
`handleActionWithIdentifier(_:forRemoteNotification:withResponseInfo:)`
`handleActionWithIdentifier(_:forLocalNotification:)`, and
`handleActionWithIdentifier(_:forLocalNotification:withResponseInfo:)`

See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015523) for more information.