# Is it possible to open the Settings app programatically in watchOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos

I'm currently using Swift to write an independent Apple Watch app for watchOS 7+. My app uses Location Services, and in case the user doesn't allow that at first, I'd like to have a button inside my watchOS app to send my user to the part of the Settings app (inside watchOS) where he can give the appropriate permissions for the app.

I know that in iOS/macOS you can use the [openSettingsURLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring) string from UIApplication to do what I want, but it's not available in watchOS and I haven't found any equivalent resource inside the WKExtension class (normally the equivalent for UIApplication in the watchOS environment, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270738/what-is-the-equivalent-of-uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-in-watchkit)).

Does anyone know if there's any way to programatically open the Apple Watch Settings app from my watchOS app?

The code below is what I'm trying to do - but (of course) it crashes since I'm not actually passing any systemURL.

```
.alert(isPresented: $alertVisible) {
                Alert (title: Text("Please allow our app to use location services in order to get Weather Data"),
                       message: Text("Go to Settings?"),
                       primaryButton: .default(Text("Settings"), action: {
                    WKExtension.shared().openSystemURL(URL(string: "")!)
                    //UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
                }),
```

Comment: You are not the only one who have to tackle exact this problem. Did you, by any chance, already find a solution?

Comment: I am afraid that "openSystemURL" is the wrong function... I tried "WKExtension.shared().openSystemURL(URL:(string:'prefs:root=WIFI')!)", but it says "URL with scheme "prefs" not supported" in log once I clickt the button with that action :(

Comment: I still don't have a solution. I posted the same question on the Apple Dev forums ([link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694269)), but no answer until now. Also tried sending a Feedback Request to Apple but still no answer either. :( I'll try sending one again this week and I suggest you do the same! To get over this right now I'm just showing a modal in my Watch app that basically says "Go to Settings > Location Services to change permissions".

Comment: Did you already find a solution?

Comment: @Pjaks unfortunately no. I actually had a talk with an Engineer at Apple and they couldn't really give me a definite answer, so I just left the solution I wrote above in the app.